# Going back to a previous scene in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, scene, poker

I am trying to add a button in my Pokergame assignment to go back from the scene where you can play (sce) to the Scene containing the main Menu (scene1).

As far as I know the method for switching scenes has to look somehow like this:

```
private void setBack() {
  view.getBackButton().setOnAction(e -> view.stage.setScene(scene1));

    }
```

Unfortunately, eclipse shows me some errors which say the stage cannot be resolved and scene1 cannot be resolved to a variable.

I will put here some additional code for a better understanding of the problem:

The Controller class

```
public class PokerGameController {
private PokerGameModel model;
private PokerGameView view;

public PokerGameController(PokerGameModel model, PokerGameView view) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;

    view.getShuffleButton().setOnAction( e -> shuffle() );
    view.getDealButton().setOnAction( e -> deal() );
    view.getBackButton().setOnAction(e -> setBack() );
    view.getAddButton().setOnAction(e -> AddnewPlayer());
}
```

The View class

```
public class PokerGameView {
private HBox players;
private ControlArea controls;

private PokerGameModel model;

public PokerGameView(Stage stage, PokerGameModel model) {
    this.model = model;

    // Creation of the Setup scene

    Label lbs = new Label("Welcome to the SE Poker Miniproject!");
    Label lbs2 = new Label("Four players max!");
    Label lbs3 = new Label("How many players are you?");

    Button chng = new Button ("Start!");

    BorderPane boot = new BorderPane();
    boot.setTop(lbs);
    boot.setCenter(chng);

    Scene scene1 = new Scene(boot, 400, 400);
    stage.setTitle("Poker");
    stage.setScene(scene1);
    stage.show();

    // Create the control area
    controls = new ControlArea();
    controls.linkDeck(model.getDeck()); // link DeckLabel to DeckOfCards in the logic

    // Put players and controls into a BorderPane
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setCenter(players);
    root.setBottom(controls);

    // Disallow resizing - which is difficult to get right with images
    stage.setResizable(false);

    // Create the scene using our layout; then display it
    Scene sce = new Scene(root);
    sce.getStylesheets().add(
            getClass().getResource("poker.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setTitle("Poker Miniproject");
    stage.setScene(scene1);
    stage.show();   

    // Switching to the main Scene
    chng.setOnAction(e-> stage.setScene(sce));
}

public PlayerPane getPlayerPane(int i) {
    return (PlayerPane) players.getChildren().get(i);
}

public Button getShuffleButton() {
    return controls.btnShuffle;
}

public Button getDealButton() {
    return controls.btnDeal;
}

public Button getBackButton() {
    return controls.btnBack;
}

public Button getAddButton() {
return controls.btnAdd;
}
```

}

And the ControlArea class:

```
public class ControlArea extends HBox{
private DeckLabel lblDeck = new DeckLabel();
private Region spacer = new Region(); // Empty spacer
Button btnShuffle = new Button("Shuffle");
Button btnDeal = new Button("Deal");
Button btnBack = new Button("Back to Menu");
Button btnAdd = new Button("New Player");

public ControlArea() {
    super(); // Always call super-constructor first !!

    this.getChildren().addAll(lblDeck, spacer, btnBack, btnAdd, btnShuffle, btnDeal);

    HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS); // Use region to absorb resizing
    this.setId("controlArea"); // Unique ID in the CSS
}
```

If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Sounds like a compilation issue. What should `scene1` refer to? Try adding an [mre] or at least a complete example of the related class.

Comment: There are no `pubic` fields in JavaFX classes (as far as I recall). Furthermore there is no `stage` property for `Node`. Usually the way to go about this retrieving the scene from the `Node` and using that scene to get the window containing it: `((Stage) node.getScene().getWindow()).setScene(newScene);` it may be preferrable to create a class responsible for changing the scenes which could easily keep track of windows/scenes...

Answer (score 1):

Pass the current scene before jumping to the new scene, then when you want to go back to the previous scene, set the scene as the passed one. All states for the previous screen can be reserved in this way, if you start a new scene from `FXMLLoader` it actually initializes a new controller/scene instead.

The previous scene controller:

```java
public class HomeController {

    // click on this button to jump to the next scene 
    @FXML
    private Button btn;

       public void onClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("NextScene.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());

        NextController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        controller.setPreScene(btn.getScene());


        Stage stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        }
}
```

The next scene controller:

```java
public class NextController {

   // click on this button to jump back to the previous home scene
     @FXML
    private Button backButton;

    private Scene preScene;

    public void setPreScene(Scene preScene) {
        this.preScene = preScene;
    }

    @FXML
    void onClickBack(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(preScene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```